# call click() function as programmatically in GWT

Tags: gwt

i want to call click event function for Button in GWT...
I tried this code but it is not working..

```
Button btnAddField = new Button();
btnAddField.setText("Add");
btnAddField.setWidth("225px");
btnAddField.addClickHandler(new btnAddFieldButtonClickListener());  


private class btnAddFieldButtonClickListener implements ClickHandler{   
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
Window.alert("Called Click Event");
}
}
```

this function wiil call at click the button
but it does not call when call this function `btnAddField.click()`

Comment: I assume the Button is added to the DOM when you call `click()`?

Comment: then do you know how can we solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve that problem by using this code

```
btnAddField.fireEvent(new ButtonClickEvent ())

private class ButtonClickEvent extends ClickEvent{
        /*To call click() function for Programmatic equivalent of the user clicking the button.*/
    }
```

It is working fine now.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try:

```
view.btnAddField.fireEvent(new ClickEvent() { } );
```

(It's a little hack, because `com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent` has protected constructor.)

or

```
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createClickEvent(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false), view.btnAddField);
```

Then, in both cases, there's no need to create separate classes and break encapsulation for handlers in order to test click events.